# 大量の画像結合方法について

Tags: python, opencv, pil

python初心者で深層学習の画像処理を勉強しています．

そこで，学習に用いた画像≧推論画像のサイズである必要があると思うのですが，推論画像に大きめの画像を用いたいです．

一般的には，画像を重複部分10%程度で分割→推論→10%重複で結合という流れみたいなのですが，最後の重複して結合するという方法がよく分かっておりません．分割のコードは以下の通りで, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...のように保存されています．

```
import cv2
path_to_img = "/~.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(path_to_img)
img_h, img_w, _ = img.shape
split_width = 1024
split_height = 1024


def start_points(size, split_size, overlap=0):
    points = [0]
    stride = int(split_size * (1-overlap))
    counter = 1
    while True:
        pt = stride * counter
        if pt + split_size >= size:
            points.append(size - split_size)
            break
        else:
            points.append(pt)
        counter += 1
    return points


X_points = start_points(img_w, split_width, 0.5)
Y_points = start_points(img_h, split_height, 0.5)

count = 1
frmt = 'jpg'

for i in Y_points:
    for j in X_points:
        split = img[i:i+split_height, j:j+split_width]
        cv2.imwrite('{}.{}'.format(count, frmt), split)
        count += 1
```

一枚の大きな背景を生成して，そこに画像を貼り付けていくというイメージなのですが，200枚ほどの画像を結合する必要があり，コードを短くしたいです．

以下のコードの編集，もしくは別のやり方についてご教授いただけないでしょうか．
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします．

```
background_img = Image.new('RGB', (8000,6000), (0,0,0))
im1 = Image.open('1.png')
im2 = Image.open('2.png')
……

combine_im = background_img.copy()
combine_im.paste(im1, (100, 50))
combine_im.paste(im2, (600, 50))
……
```

Comment: 各々の画像サイズは同じですか異なりますか？異なる場合配置考えないといけないけど同じなら単に複数ファイル名与えて縦横の個数指定するくらいで済むので

Comment: 遅くなりましてすみません。画像サイズは全て同じで、1024*1024pixel以下で分割することを考えております。